# Where to find PyUnicodeUCS4_Decode?

Tags: python

I am trying to test some 32 bit software on an Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit machine.  After getting the 32 bit libraries installed, it now fails with :

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Nov  4 2011, 19:26:59)
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pyexpat import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_Decode
```

Any ideas on where to find `PyUnicodeUCS4_Decode`?   I installed PyXML-0.8.4, but that didn't help.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/xml-sig/2003-January/008920.html) seemed to explain that it might be due to python supporting two different Unicode modes UCS2 (the default), and UCS4.  It suggests recompiling from scratch.

You can [download the package directly](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/pyxml/PyXML-0.8.4.tar.gz?modtime=1101741917&big_mirror=0) and then compile on your machine by running:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```